# Using one UPDATE query for more than a single row/ colum

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

How would I go about putting my code into one UPDATE statement, bearing in mind that i'm doing a lot of conditional statements:

```
    $updateTbl1 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerAge = t.customerAge WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerAge != t.customerAge );";
    $updateTbl2 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerCode = t.customerCode WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerCode != t.customerCode);";
    $updateTbl3 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerName = t.customerName WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerName != t.customerName);";
    $updateTbl4 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerEmail = t.customerEmail WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerEmail != t.customerEmail);";
    $updateTbl5 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerAddress = t.customerAddress WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerAddress != t.customerAddress);";
    $updateTbl6 =   "UPDATE $tableNameOrig o, $tableNameTemp t SET o.customerAdded = t.customerAdded WHERE o.id = t.id AND (o.customerAdded != t.customerAdded);";

    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl1));
    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl2));
    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl3));
    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl4));
    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl5));
    (mysqli_query($con,$updateTbl6));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not really using one `UPDATE` but it is using one PHP Method Call, `mysqli_multi_query($con, $updateTbl1.$updateTbl2);` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE $tableNameOrig o
  JOIN $tableNameTemp t
    ON o.id = t.id
   SET o.customerAge = t.customerAge,
       o.customerCode = t.customerCode,
       o.customerName = t.customerName,
       o.customerEmail = t.customerEmail,
       o.customerAddress = t.customerAddress,
       o.customerAdded = t.customerAdded
```

Your other conditions are meaningless.

Comment: But I only want it to update if the values are different? Which is why I have a condition testing is the values are not equal.

Comment: @LazyTotoro Yes, but if the values are the same, then it doesn't really matter does it.. I'm pretty sure this is the fastest way. MySQL let's you know how many rows are matched and how many are changed anyway.

Comment: I realise this now, the table also has a column which won't be getting batch-updated so I can just leave that out of the query. Thanks for your help and explanation!